# Keycloak Rest Api Reset password via Postman

Tags: keycloak, user-management, keycloak-rest-api

I am trying to leverage the Keycloak Rest Api functionality to reset passwords for the users configured in Keycloak via Postman.

**Steps performed**:

1. I got the access token from http://127.0.0.1:8080/realms/:realmname/protocol/openid-connect/token for the user I want to change.
2. Then I am trying to use the same access token as Bearer Token and perform the PUT operation on http://127.0.0.1:8080/admin/realms/:realmName/users/:id/reset-password following the  [Keycloak Api Documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/15.0/rest-api/).

**Headers**
[image]
**Body**
[image]
**Response**
[image]

**User permissions**
[image]

I keep on getting **403 Forbidden Error** with no real reason, I even gave realm-management permission to the user but with no success. I've already gone through similar questions but have no expected resolution.
I would appreciate any feedback or leads to resolve the issue. TIA

Comment: Did you analyse the token, you obtained with for exaample jwt.io?

Comment: Yes, I did analyze the token, the problem was I gave it the `manage-realm` role instead of `manage-users`. After changing the same, I was able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a user21 needs `manage-users` role (not `manage-realm`) for changing `reset-password`

[image]

Steps

#1 launching latest Keycloak

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:21.0.1 start-dev
```

#2 Create `my-realm`

#3 Create `user21`

#4 Assign she has `manage-users` role

#5 Create `user1`

#6 Get `user21` access token and set the Postman's global available

```
http://localhost:8080/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
pm.globals.set("user21-token", jsonData.access_token);
```

[image]

[image]

#7 Get all of users for getting `{user1-uuid}`

```
http://localhost:8080/admin/realms/my-realm/users
```

#8 Change password for `user1`

With `user21-token`

In Input Body of PUT call.

```
{
    "temporary": false,
    "type": "password",
    "value": "12345"
}
```

[image]

Call `reset-password` API

[image]

You can confirm `user21`'s role mapping API.

```
GET {Keycloak API}/admin/realms/{realm-name}/users/{user-uuid}/role-mappings
```

[image]

Comment: As suggested, the missing `manage-users` role was the issue. I was able to successfully change the password after making the changes. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome. I am happy to hear you got it.