# Create Keycloak role to manage password across realms

Tags: keycloak

We are setting up Keycloak to provide authentication into our applications for our customers. Each customer will be assigned their own realm. Customer admins will be given permission within their realm to perform operations.

A small group within our support group will have super-admin privileges across all realms. However, we'd like to enable a broader group of our support reps to manage user password resets across all customer realms.

Is it possible to create a role in Keycloak that has limited permissions (e.g., less than admin) across all realms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do by assigning all of realm's `manage-users` for `customer_admin` user at `master` realm.

[image]

##### Step 0

launching  latest Keycloak by docker

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:23.0.5 start-dev
```

##### Step 1

Create two realms (or more)
[image]

##### Step 2

Add User for each realms
[image]

[image]

##### Step 3

Add `customer_admin` user at master
[image]

##### Step 4

[image]

Click down arrow to select 'Filter by clients` menu

[image]

Will be pop up `Assign roles to customer_admin` dialog
Then select all of realms's `manage-users` role.

[image]

##### Reset password by REST API

In here [Keycloak Rest Api Reset password via Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75651043/keycloak-rest-api-reset-password-via-postman/75654512#75654512) more detail information.

Comment: @Bubba, You are welcome. Happy to code!